# Swagger documentation tools for a Rails API application

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I googled a little bit to find a proper and easy to implement way to generate [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) documentation for an existing Rails API app. To be short, there are 2 ways of implementation: either via controllers, models or via Rspec controller/request specs. The list is not too long and the choice is not so easy to make:

1. [swagger-docs](https://github.com/richhollis/swagger-docs) gem, - the oldest one. Pros: implementation is to be
   done in  controllers. Cons: does not support Swagger **V2** version
   and limited to **1.2** only.
2. [swagger-blocks](https://github.com/fotinakis/swagger-blocks) gem, - improved version of swagger-docs, supports Swagger V2 version, implementation is to be done in controllers, models. But I couldn't make it work, [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io/) could not parse the generated json file.
3. [rswag](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/rswag) gem:  extends rspec-rails "request specs" with a Swagger-based DSL. Personally, I found it really difficult to implement in an existing Rails app for 2 reasons:

   - you will have to modify existing request specs
   - request specs look really weird and the syntax is not *RSpec*-ish.
4. [rspec-rails-swagger](https://github.com/drewish/rspec-rails-swagger) gem: implementation via request specs. The same cons as above.

Does anybody know other gems to generate Swagger documentation for an existing Rails API app ? Any suggestions are welcome ! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The solution I came to is as to use [rswag](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/rswag) gem and [rspec-rails-swagger](https://github.com/drewish/rspec-rails-swagger) gem
- install rswag gem by adding the following in your Gemfile:

```
#Gemfile
gem 'rswag-api'
gem 'rswag-ui'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails',         '~> 3.8.1'
  gem 'rspec-rails-swagger', '~> 0.1.5'
...
end
```

- run `bundle install``
- run `rails g rswag:install` to generate `swagger_helper.rb`
- to create a new request spec with rspec-rails-swagger, run `rails generate rspec:swagger PostsController`(adapt the name to your won controller you want to write the spec).
- write some specs as explained in rspec-rails-swagger [README](https://github.com/drewish/rspec-rails-swagger#rspec-dsl)
- run `bundle exec rake swagger` to generate a `swagger.json` file.
- mount RSwag API and RSwag UI engines by adding the following lines to your `routes.rb` file:

```
#../config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Rswag::Ui::Engine => '/api-docs'
  mount Rswag::Api::Engine => '/api-docs'
...#other routes come here
end
```

- start up your rails server with `rails s`
- navigate to `localhost:3000/api-docs` to see the generated Swagger documentation.

**Note**: it works pretty good and replies to the client requirements, i.e.:

- generate Swagger 2.0 compatible documentation
- be able to execute requests directly from Swagger interface to see the real data

I removed `rswag-specs` gem from `Gemfile` because it could not validate response schema returned in [JSON API format](https://jsonapi.org/format/) by [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) gem I use in my Rails API app. I had always to:

- generate the docs
- comment out failing tests
- then uncomment failing tests in case I need to generate some new documentation, that was really hard to maintain.

Now request specs are validated by RSpec and rspec-rails-swagger at the same time without hassle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the reason to use both rswag AND rspec-rails-swagger at the same time, is it related to your specific requirement regarding JSON API validation?

Otherwise I believe that rswag can do anything rspec-rails-swagger does, I tried both and they're very very similar (almost to the extent that one seems a fork of the other), but rswag has more Github stars (if that means anything), seems slightly easier to use, and most importantly has a Swagger UI built in ...

I think for the majority of use cases you wouldn't need to use both rswag and rspec-rails-swagger.

Comment: rspec-rails-swagger [DOES NOT INCLUDE](https://github.com/drewish/rspec-rails-swagger#generate-the-json-or-yaml) Swagger UI to render the generated JSON doccs file. That was one of the reasons to use both. Another one - is that RSwag does not parse properly active_model_serializers responses and some tests just failed.

Comment: Got it - rspec-rails-swagger does not include a UI, rswag does ... so what I meant was, why not just use rswag, but you've answered that one already, I asked a question which was already answered ... if ever we run into the same sort of problem then at least I know we could add rspec-rails-swagger to make it work again (maybe with some minor changes to the RSpec tests)

Comment: @belgoros - have you managed to generate swagger docs when using the jsonapi-resources gem?  Both that gem and rswag are what I need but I don't think they work well together.

Comment: Nope, I don’t use jsonapi-resources gem.

Answer (score 0):

Our working solution is to use:

- [swagger-blocks](https://github.com/fotinakis/swagger-blocks) gem to generate the Swagger JSON
- [Swagger UI Console Chrome
  Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/swagger-ui-console/ljlmonadebogfjabhkppkoohjkjclfai?hl=en) to provide the Swagger UI